# How to determine current compilation target in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli, c-preprocessor

Generally, when code is being compiled by cl.exe using the /clr switch, it gets compiled to MSIL to be run by the CLR. It is, however, entirely possible to create mixed-mode assemblies, which include native code, using the `#pragma unmanaged` directive.

I have some lines of code which I'd like to behave a bit differently when compiled for the CLR and when compiled for the native platform. I have checked the predefined preprocessor macros on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx), but, sadly, I have not been able to find one that is able to tell, at the point of its usage, whether the current bit of code is being compiled for MSIL or the native architecture. What I want, basically, is

```
#if defined(IS_THIS_MANAGED_NOW)
#define THROW throw gcnew System::Exception("Fancy managed exception");
#else
#define THROW throw "Not-so-fancy native string";
#endif
```

or

```
#if defined(IS_THIS_MANAGED_NOW)
#define BSR(value, result) result = BitScanReverseManagedImpl(value)
#else
#define BSR(value, result) _BitScanReverse(&result, value);
#endif
```

to work correctly based on the current compilation target. (Please note these were only examples to illustrate the problem, not live code samples.)

Edit:

The following program

```
void print(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    print();

    return 0;
}

#pragma unmanaged
#include <cstdio>

void print()
{
    std::printf("__CLR_VER = %d\n", __CLR_VER);
    std::printf("__cplusplus_cli = %d\n", __cplusplus_cli);
    std::printf("_MANAGED = %d\n", _MANAGED);
}
```

demonstrates that these `#define`s remain in effect if used with /clr even if the function is being compiled for native target.

Comment: You only get a preprocessor symbol that tells you that /clr is in effect.  When you switch back-and-forth with #pragma then it is up to you to keep track.  Fairly mysterious that this would be an issue btw, the #pragma is never far away and never falls from the sky.  Splitting up the code across source code files is another obvious approach, the /clr option applies to each source code file individually.

Comment: Avoid the defined. Your BSR sample can easily use a function that uses the specific types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my understanding, it is not possible to have an `#ifdef` based on a `#pragma` directive. `#ifdef` is processed during the preprocessor phase of compilation, which is before the compiler has processed the `#pragma` directives during a later phase.

The closest thing to that would be to use `#ifdef __cplusplus`. That switches on how the file is being compiled (with or without the `/clr` flag), rather than on the `#pragma`. Depending on how your project is set up, this may be granular enough, since you can change that setting on a per-file basis.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus_cli
#define THROW throw gcnew System::Exception("Fancy managed exception");
#else
#define THROW throw "Not-so-fancy native string";
#endif
```

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question, as __cplusplus_cli remains in effect (defined) even after a #pragma unmanaged directive.

Comment: If you want a `#ifdef` to reflect the results of #pragma managed/unmanaged, I don't think that's possible. `#ifdef` is handled in the preprocessor step, `#pragma unmanaged` is the code generation step. Besides which, if you're using `#pragma managed` and `#pragma unmanaged` in your code, why can't you `#define IS_THIS_MANAGED_NOW` and `#undef IS_THIS_MANAGED_NOW` at the same time?

Comment: The code is intended to be used as a "library", so detection of the current mode and sharing a codebase would be preferable.

I'm sorry to hear this is not possible; though not totally unexpected.

Comment: I think that it is possible, you just need to think about it differently. When compiling a C++ project, you get C++ code. When compiling a C++/CLI project, you get .Net code. Think of it based on the project type, not based on a #pragma.

Comment: There are two related programs being made, a service and a client, with a decent amount of code shared. The service is entirely native, the client has its GUI made using WPF, hence the need for C++/CLI. That aside, the client code is also mostly native, and I would like to keep it that way, without including random CLR calls just because the project itself is compiled with /clr.

If you make an answer saying it's not possible to do what I asked, I'll be happy to mark it as accepted.

Comment: See edit. You can switch which files are compiled with `/clr`, that may be sufficient for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As workaround you can disable `_MANAGED` or set it to 0 manually then restore it.

```cpp
#pragma managed(push, off)
#pragma push_macro( "_MANAGED" )
#undef _MANAGED

#if defined(_MANAGED)
#define THROW throw gcnew System::Exception("Fancy managed exception");
#else
#define THROW throw "Not-so-fancy native string";
#endif

void foo()
{
    THROW;
}

#pragma pop_macro( "_MANAGED" )
#pragma managed(pop)

int main()
{
}
```

The source: [social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ff6b7e62-7695-4797-8308-5cc2bcf388cf/pragma-unmanaged-and-managed-macro?forum=vclanguage)